# best_in_place - Have to Refresh Page to Show Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, best-in-place

I am using cocoon for nested forms. So when I add an experiment I can add variations all through the same form. I installed `gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.1`' to make editing easier, and I am having a problem after the update. 
Through the best_in_place helper, I can click a description and change it. The database is updated and the change shows for a moment, then disappears, going back to what it was prior to my change. If I refresh the page, my changes are visible. So it takes refreshing the page to display the changes. 
I couldn’t get best_in_place to work correctly and after reading up, I ended up sticking a route outside of my nested routes to get it to work

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :advertisers do
        resources :experiments do
          resources :variations
       end
     end
  resources :variations, only: [:update, :show]
```

I use best_in_place inside my **experiments show.html.erb** file

```
<% @experiment.variations.each do |variation| %>   
                        <h3><i class="fa fa-square"></i> <%= variation.name %></h3>
                            <p class="data-row">
                              <span class="data-name">URL</span>                            
                              <span class="data-value"><%= variation.url %></span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="data-row">
                              <span class="data-name">Description</span>                              
                              <div><%= best_in_place variation, :description, :as => :textarea %></div>
                            </p>
    <% end %>
```

I think the problem is in my variations update action. Here is my **Variations controller**

```
class VariationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_variation   

def update
    @variation.update(variation_params) 
end   

private

    def variation_params
        params.require(:variation).permit(:description, :name, :url)
    end

    def find_variation
        @variation = Variation.find(params[:id])
    end


end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how I fixed it, but its working. Here is what I did.

I changed my update action to

```
respond_to :html, :json


def update

    @variation = Variation.find(params[:id])
    @variation.update_attributes(variation_params)
    respond_with(@variations)
end
```

All works.

UPDATE: best_in_place uses json underneath, but the controller didnt respond to json properly. So by adding respond_to and respond_with it works properly.